# Classification of the Summit supercomputer

Tags: classification, topology

Can we classify a supercomputer in more than one group? For example, Flynn's classification, classification according to topology, classification according to memory access.
For the Summit supercomputer, I have found no sources on these topics, except for Flynn's classification. How can I classify it in other categories, for example by topology?

Comment: You can use any classification you want. The goal of classifications is to help us understand our world. We can use them as we see fit. It is certainly the case that every object can be understood from many different angles. For example, my laptop is (1) a laptop rather than a desktop, (2) from a certain year, (3) runs a certain operating system, (4) produced by a certain company, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a really revealing comment for me. I wish I could find resources on these classifications for the Summit supercomputer as well.